# Flex - why am I missing some spark components (but not all)?

Tags: css, forms, apache-flex

I have a component (an `s:TitleWindow`) that I created and inside I have some `<mx:FormItem ...>` blocks.

There is supposed to be an equivalent `<s:FormItem...>`, but when I type `<s:` and press control space I get a list of spark components, but FormItem is not one.   If I type it, the compiler generates an error that it does not exist.

My project settings are set to "MX+Spark".

The reason for this is I want to some some css styling to right justify the form and the examples I have seen all use the syntax of  `s|FormItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081728/flex-forms-getting-labels-to-line-up-right-justified) that the spark form tag is available only with Flex 4.5.  This includes tags within a Spark form (e.g. `<s:FormItem />`).  Flex 4 doesn't seem to include the Spark Form tags.  This may be the issue:

> "Spark was a new component architecture introduced in Flex 4. I consider the architecture "complete" but not all MX components have been implemented as Spark components yet. The Spark Form tag is slated for Flex Hero expected early next year and is only available in pre-release builds."

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I did figure out by the way that I could get right justification on the formitem labels by making sure they are in a form container.   I did not have them in a form container.   Thats for the clarification on the spark/form/4.5.

Answer (score 0):

in the transition to version 4.0 not all the components were ported to spark. another example is datagrid, you only have mx:datagrid for now (in 4.5 you will have s:datagrid). you just have to wait that the transition is completed...

the css you are referring to were for 4.0 or 4.5 ?

Comment: You realize that 4.5 was released earlier this week?  It includes both a spark DataGrid (as you mention) and a spark Form.